# Order by x DESC - but only continuous rows

Tags: mysql, order-by

I have a table with an ID (integer) and a text field (the name). My current query looks like this:

`SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id <= X ORDER BY id DESC`

X is an ID I get from another query. What this query currently does is it outputs all the entries lower than the ID I put into, ordered by ID.

What I'd like to achieve is that this is only done until the first "gap" in the IDs - for example, with a table like this:

```
id      name
1       Test 1
2       Test 2
3       Test 3
6       Test 6
7       Test 7
8       Test 8
9       Test 9
```

I'd like to have a query which only returns the following set for `X = 8`:

```
id      name
8       Test 8
7       Test 7
6       Test 6
```

Because then, there is a gap in the IDs (ID 5 is missing), and then I don't need the other lower IDs.

How could that be done?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM data
WHERE id <= 8 AND id >= (
    SELECT MAX(d1.id)
    FROM data d1
    LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.id = d1.id - 1
    WHERE d2.id IS NULL
)
ORDER BY id DESC
;
```

The subquery look for the first gap (i.e. 5 to 6). See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dfe2b/8/0).

#### Output:

```
id | name 
 8 | Test 8 
 7 | Test 7 
 6 | Test 6
```